# undefined reference to `__imp_AssocQueryStringA'

Tags: c++

I am trying to open a jpg but it is not working when there is no file association.

```
ShellExecute(0, 0, file_path.c_str(), 0, 0 , SW_SHOW );
```

So I am using code I found on stackoverflow to check if there is an existing association with jpg but this returns: undefined reference to `__imp_AssocQueryStringA'

My compily args looks like that:

```
args": [
          "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
          "-g",
          "-std=c++20",
          "-L.",
          //"-mwindows",
          //"-static",
          "-static-libgcc",
          "-static-libstdc++",
          "-lshlwapi",
          //"-libs",
          "${file}",
          "Resources\\icon.res",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ]
```

And my environment is VSC with msys64.

My code looks like that:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

bool Test_FileExtension(const std::string& weirdassextension);

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
            HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
            LPTSTR    lpCmdLine, 
            int       cmdShow) {
    bool test = Test_FileExtension("jpg");
std::cout << test << std::endl;
}

bool Test_FileExtension(const std::string& weirdassextension){


     WCHAR wbuffPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
     DWORD dwszBuffPath = MAX_PATH;
     std::wstring stemp = L"." +  std::wstring(weirdassextension.begin(), weirdassextension.end());
     LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();

     HRESULT hR = ::AssocQueryStringW(ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN, 
         ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
         sw,
         NULL,
         wbuffPath,
         &dwszBuffPath);

    if(hR == 0x80070483)   // HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NO_ASSOCIATION)
    {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? The shlwapi.h exists under: "C:\Program Files\msys64\mingw64\include\shlwapi.h"

Comment: The docs page for that function say to link to `Shlwapi.lib`. Have you?

Comment: @MikeVine, I added the same comment earlier, then realized that Shlwapi.lib is in the OPs args -lshlwapi

Comment: `-lshlwapi` must come *after* `${file}`.

Comment: @Botje, that seems to fix it. Thank you a lot. Give me some minutes to test it